# Search Between 2 Dates Venti Calendar Plugin

Tags: search, plugin-ventievents

I am using the Venti Events Calendar Plugin. I was wondering how I could go about searching for events between 2 dates.

I can display events between 2 dates below, using the .between parameter. But I have not figured out how to incorporate this into a search.

```
{% set events = craft.venti.events.between('2016-04-01 00:00:00','2016-05-19 00:00:00') %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure this out on my own.  There's a good chance this solution will work for searching for entries between custom date fields using Craft's standard entry system (not the Venti Plugin) as well.

```
 {% set start = craft.request.param('startMonth') %}
 {% set end = craft.request.param('endMonth') %}
 {% set entries = craft.venti.events.startDate('and', '>= ' ~ start|date('Y-m-d'), '<= ' ~ end|date('Y-m-d')) %}

 {% for entry in entries %}
      <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
 {% endfor %}
```